# Is there a better way to group these <p> tags?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a menu that has links that are centered but I don't know if there is a better way to do it (like I wanna know if there is a way I can do it with just one

tag). Any help is appreciated.

```css
.menuBar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: plum;
  display: flex;
}

.menuBar>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
  <a href="index.html" title="Home">
    <img src="homeButton.png" alt="Home Button" id="homeButton" width="50" height="50">
  </a>
  <p>
    <a href="bubble.html" title="Bubble Sort">Bubble Sort</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="insertion.html" title="Insertion Sort">Insertion Sort</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="merge.html" title="Merge Sort">Merge Sort</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="quick.html" title="Quick Sort">Quick Sort</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ewwwwwww...  this is horrific! I will leave it at that.

Comment: @SeanStopnik haha still learning... Rome wasn't built in a day eh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for exactly but the code below will center the menu items nicely with the space around them and minimum necessary number of elements in a `div`, and less `css`:

```
<body>
    <div class="menuBar">
      <a href="index.html" title="Home">
        <img src="homeButton.png" alt="Home Button" id = "homeButton" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
      <a href="bubble.html" title="Bubble Sort">Bubble Sort</a>
      <a href="insertion.html" title="Insertion Sort">Insertion Sort</a>
      <a href="merge.html" title="Merge Sort">Merge Sort</a>
      <a href="quick.html" title="Quick Sort">Quick Sort</a>
    </div>
</body>

.menuBar{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 5vh;
 background-color: plum;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pL8fvbqc/1/). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For a nav, you can use the `<nav>` element. Also, for navs, you can use an unordered list (`ul`) and make the children `li` then `a`. Or, you can just have a tags making the first one styled different.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple CSS grid with `auto` sized columns:

```css
.menuBar {
  width: calc(100vw - 16px); /* 2*8px body margin */
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: plum;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menuBar>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
  <a href="index.html" title="Home">
    <img src="homeButton.png" alt="Home Button" id="homeButton" width="50" height="50">
  </a>
  <a href="bubble.html" title="Bubble Sort">Bubble Sort</a>
  <a href="insertion.html" title="Insertion Sort">Insertion Sort</a>
  <a href="merge.html" title="Merge Sort">Merge Sort</a>
  <a href="quick.html" title="Quick Sort">Quick Sort</a>
</div>
```